# cross platform real time data

Tags: android, ios, push, real-time

I am working a hard project which need to push data notification from the backend server to ios, android client and browser as well. based on current situation, the following options are available 
1)COMET style push server
2)Socket server 
3)Websocket

Just want to know which one is the best choice for this situation. welcome to discuss rela time push data here to learn much.

Comment: without knowing more about your situation there is no way that we could tell you which one is "best"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the payload you are pushing to iOS you might actually be able to use Apple Push Notification and save yourself some development headache.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a Backend as a Service provider, like Kinvey? I know they can make push notifications much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Are looking for a solution to push updates while the apps are open and in-use on mobile?  PubNub (www.pubnub.com) provides a publish subscribe API for all major platforms. You can use it to push data to mobile, web and desktop clients.  It works on all browsers and can bypass proxies.  it has also the ability to deal with dropped cell signals by storing messages in a history queue and then delivering those messages once a devices comes back on line.   You can find all tutorials, and documentation here: http://www.pubnub.com/devcenter. (disclaimer - I work for PubNub)